# Counting paths with reflection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, analysis, discrete-mathematics

Fix two points $y=0$ and $x=(x_1,x_2).$ We assume without loss of generality that $x_1 ,x_2 \ge 0.$

Let $S=x_1+x_2.$ The number of paths on $\mathbb Z^2$ from $y=0$ to $x=(x_1,x_2)$ of length 
$n=2m+S$ is given as

$$f_2(m) = n!\sum_{a_1 + a_2 = m}\frac{1}{a_1!a_2!(a_1 + x_1)!(a_2 + x_2)!} = \binom n m \sum_{a = 0}^m\binom m a \binom{m + S}{a + x_1},$$

see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3476929

So to be precise, the paths are allowed to be self-intersecting (and you can go back and forth) and can move horizontically and vertically.

Now, if along such a path we go in the $n$-th step from one point $z_1$ to some point $z_2$ where $\Vert z_1-z_2 \Vert_{\infty}=1$ and then back to $z_1$ in the $n+1$-st step, then I call this step a *reflection*.

Let $f_2(m)$ be the total number of paths as above and let $f^{even}_2(m)$ be the number of paths with an even number of reflections and $f^{odd}_2(m)$ the number of paths with an odd number of reflections such that

$$f_2(m)=f^{\text{even}}_2(m)+f^{\text{odd}}_2(m).$$

I would like to know whether we can explicitly bound

$$\vert f^{\text{even}}_2(m)-f^{\text{odd}}_2(m) \vert? $$

My intuition is somehow that $\vert f^{\text{even}}_2(m)-f^{\text{odd}}_2(m) \vert$ should be significantly smaller than $f_2(m).$

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the $\Vert \Vert_\infty$ norm? Does it refer to the $\ell^\infty$ norm in this case? You seem to drop it when you're asking about the bounds

Comment: It is the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm and no, I just want to say that we move from some point, let's say (4,5) to a point (3,5) for example

Comment: I think $m$ is the total number of "incorrect" steps - i.e. steps either to the left or down. Is that right?

Comment: To go from y to x you require S many steps. If you do not go directly from y to x, then you will make $2m$ unnecessary steps.

Comment: The probabilistic argument (reflections are independent, then law of large numbers) just gives you that $\frac1{f_2(m)} |f_2^{even}(m)-f_2^{odd}(m)| \to 0$. It does not directly apply here since you are conditioning the random walk to end at $x$, but asymptotically this should still be true. However, what you wrote without the $1/f_2(m)$ factor is certainly not true (since it would imply that $f_2^{even}(m) = f_2^{odd}(m)$ for all sufficiently large $m$.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer you are right, this was a bit too optimistic, I deleted that part. However, I do not understand why you say they coincide for sufficiently large $m$. Why is it not possible that their difference just goes to zero?

Comment: @Sascha: Because they are both integers, so you have an integer sequence converging, which can only happen if it is eventually constant. The bound from the law of large numbers is non-explicit and quite weak, it is certainly possible that you get a better explicit bound in this case, but I don't have any great ideas.

Comment: @LukasGeyer ah yes, you are right of course

Comment: you may want to look at some references that discuss "restricted reversals"