# Lattice paths of on $\mathbb{Z^d}$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices

Consider an infinite lattice on $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Neighbours of a point on the lattice are given as von-Neumann neighbours, i.e a neighbour of a point $(x, y)$ are the set

$$
\{(x+1,\ y),(x-1,\ y),(x,\ y+1),(x,\ y-1)\}.
$$

Now, define the set of $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ nearest neighbours as

$$
x^{(k)}=\{\mathrm{neighbours\ of\ }x_{k-1}|x_{k-1}\in\ x^{(k-1)}\},
$$

with $x^{(0)} = x$. In this way, points can be in $x^{(k)}$ multiple times, for example, $x$ is in $x^{(2)}$ four times.

In particular, the multiplicity of $x$ in $x^{(k)}$ for even $k$ is given by ${2k \choose k}^2$.

The problem of finding the multiplicities of point in $x$ is equivalent to finding the number of lattice paths from the central point to the point being considered as a $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ neighbour given that the lattice path has length $k$.

I would be interested to know if there was a nice form to get the multiplicities of any point in a given set of $x^{(k)}$, similar to the form given for the central point $x$.

Comment: As long as $d=2$, there is a nice formula. Is your post also asking about larger $d$?

Comment: Preferably asking for any value of $d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $d=2$, the multiplicity of $(x+a,x+b)$ in $x^{(k)}$ is $$\binom{k}{\frac{k+a-b}2}\times \binom{k}{\frac{k+a+b}2},$$ when $a+b$ has the same parity as $k$, and is zero otherwise. I gave a combinatorial proof in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058039

For $d\ge 3$, there is no nice formula, but you can find some complicated formulae in the answers to [Number of paths on $\mathbb Z^d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208650/number-of-paths-on-mathbb-zd)

Comment: This is perfect - thanks